# How to merge elements of two string arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

Let's say we have two JavaScript arrays like this:

```js
var firstNameArray = ["Jack", "Indiana", "James"];

var lastNameArray = ["Sparrow", "Jones", "Bond"];
```

I want the output to be:

```js
var result = ["Jack Sparrow","Indiana Jones","James Bond"];
```

***Note:*** `firstNameArray` and `lastNameArray` can have dynamic values.

How do I merge elements of two arrays in JavaScript to get this result?

Comment: Can you also post your findings and your efforts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var result = firstNameArray.map((it,index)=>it+' '+lastNameArray[index]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using traditional `for` loop

```js
var firstNameArray = ["Jack", "Indiana", "James"];
var lastNameArray = ["Sparrow", "Jones", "Bond"];
let merged = [];
for (let i = 0; i < firstNameArray.length; i++) {
  merged.push(`${firstNameArray[i]} ${lastNameArray[i]}`)
}
console.log(merged);
```

Using `reduce` method

```js
var firstNameArray = ["Jack", "Indiana", "James"];
var lastNameArray = ["Sparrow", "Jones", "Bond"];
const merged = firstNameArray.reduce((arr, item, index) => {
  arr.push(`${item} ${lastNameArray[index]}`);
  return arr;
}, []);
console.log(merged)
```

Using `map`

```js
var firstNameArray = ["Jack", "Indiana", "James"];
var lastNameArray = ["Sparrow", "Jones", "Bond"];
let merged = firstNameArray.map((e,index) => {
  return `${e} ${lastNameArray[index]}`;
});
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate any array (assuming both the arrays will contain equal number of elements) using map and build the new set with concatenation both the array elements based on index.

Demo **:**

```js
const firstNameArray = ["Jack", "Indiana", "James"];

const lastNameArray = ["Sparrow", "Jones", "Bond"];

const finalArray = firstNameArray.map((item, index) => {
    return `${item} ${lastNameArray[index]}`
});

console.log(finalArray);
```